# open a pdf document from an url with only partial filename

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use javascript to open a .pdf link on chrome for which I know the base URL and the beginning of the .pdf, however I'm missing the last caracters of the file.

I was thinking I could maybe loop through all the files located in the specific folder of the URL and check if one of them was starting like the file I wanted but couldn't get very far as I didn't succeed in getting the list of all filenames from that URL as I only found window.location.href but that doesn't refer to my URL but to where I'm at currently.

Even better I figured I could provide the start of an url with a wildcard and that it'd open the first document matching this, kind of the "like" in sql but it didn't work either.

```
StringToFind =  "recordnumber123";

if(window.location.href.indexOf(stringToFind) > -1) {
    filename = name_of_the_file_that_matched;
}
```

My base URL is something like: 
"https://www.documents.com/records/"
my filenames are like 
"recordnumber123_201810091102453651.pdf" 
and I only know the part:
"recordnumber123" and that it is a .pdf. 
The numbers after the underscore are added by the system as some sort of timestamp but I don't have a way to get them.

If this isn't possible, I also know the server on which these files are stored (for which I have the exact name) but I couldn't manage to open the file from chrome. 
I tried to open it using

href="http://file://///https://www.documents.com/records/recordnumber123_201819124564.pdf"
but it redirects me to http://ww8.file.com/

and    href="file://///https://www.documents.com/records/recordnumber123_201819124564.pdf"

but it doesn't launch anything. From what I read it seems that it's not allowed anymore to access files direclty like this from Chrome?

I can only use chrome and I cannot install specific plugins...

Comment: it sounds like you are trying to build a string (the entire url) without having all the data.

Comment: You cannot do this with JS, you will need to find a way to get the list of files from the server.

Your only option in JS is to note the pattern with the timestamp and do ajax calls to iterate through the pattern to get the file you want.

Comment: You should do this in server side by passing the known string. Create a web service which accepts the string and returns the file.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I'll try to find the exact timestamps